# simple Android sqlite based app crashing

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I am trying to learn some android sql database basics. So, i found an example online (screaming Penguin i believe) that illustrates a one column, one table sql database that uses a textveiw to display its values.  So i was trying to expand upon this databse by adding two more columns and giving them values as well.  I was successful at building the actual database( i pulled it from the DDMS and viewed it...it's fine)but my app keeps crashing in my emulator and i cant figure out what i am doing wrong.  Below i have one activity and an additional class called DataHelper and my main xml file.

```
CartoonDb2 Activity:


 package your.cartoon2.namespace;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import java.util.List;

 public class CartoonDb2Activity extends Activity {
  private TextView output;
  private DataHelper dh;
  @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
      this.output = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.out_text);
      this.dh = new DataHelper(this);
     this.dh.deleteAll();
     this.dh.insert("Porky Pig","DaffyDuck", "wolverine");/////this too////////////////
     this.dh.insert("Foghorn Leghorn","superman","green lantern");///////////////////
      this.dh.insert("Yosemite Sam","bugs bunny","mighty mouse");//////////////////////
     List<String> names = this.dh.selectAll();
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.append("Names in database:\n");
     for (String name : names) {
     sb.append(name + "\n");
     }
    Log.d("EXAMPLE", "names size - " + names.size());
     this.output.setText(sb.toString());
    }
   }
```

DataHelper class:

```
 package your.cartoon2.namespace;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
 import android.util.Log;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 public class DataHelper {
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "example.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
  private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";

  private Context context;
  private SQLiteDatabase db;
  private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
  private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME
    + "(name1,name2,name3)values (?,?,?)";
  public DataHelper(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
   OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
   this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
  }
  public long insert(String name1,String name2, String name3) {
   this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name1);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(2, name2);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(3, name3);
   return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
 }
  public void deleteAll() {
   this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
  }
  public List<String> selectAll() {
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "name1","name2","name3" },
     null, null, null, null, "name desc");
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
     list.add(cursor.getString(0));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
   if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
   cursor.close();
   }
  return list;
  }
   private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   OpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
      + "            (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name1 text,name2 text,name3 text)");
   }
   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     Log.w("Example",
      "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
   }
  }
 }
```

main xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
 <TextView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/hello" />
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/out_text"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd better to add exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

[Android database tutorial](http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/#title) may be help you.